# Can't send mail with Laravel4

Tags: php, email, laravel

I'm trying to send an email from localhost and using the Laravel4 mail function.
I made a route to this :

```
    Route::get('/mail', function(){
      Mail::send('emails.welcome', array('firstname' => 'Marcin'), function($message)
      {
        $message->to('margolc@interia.pl', 'John Smith')
                ->subject('Welcome!');
      });
    });
```

and my mail.php configuration

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => 'adress@gmail.com', 'name' => 'my_name'),
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => 'my_login@gmail.com',
'password' => 'my_pass',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => true,
```

I dont receive any errors when I go to public/mail but I dont recive mail too

Comment: Are you wanting to "actually" send the email - or trying to find the dump of it?

Comment: Did you check your spam folder? did you check sendmail's log to see if it actually sent anything? PHP doesn't DELIVER the mail, it basicaly just does the equivalent of walking it down the street corner and dropping your envelope into the mail box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things

Port should be '465' for gmail ssl

```
'port' => 465,
```

and you have 'pretend' set to true - so no email will be sent!

```
'pretend' => false
```

If you actually dont want to send the email, leave `pretend => true` and just view the `app/storage/logs` folder for the 'fake' email

Comment: No problems. If my answer has helped you, please remember to upvote and mark it correct :)

Comment: I will just have to wait 5mins ;)